# Language string constant PHP link

Tags: php, hyperlink, joomla

can anybody advice how can I replace that "all" link with language constant string which is possible to translate? I would like to use Joomla override language later in administration. Like it is described here: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla

```
<a href="/<?php echo EBR::_('index.php?option=com_easyblog&view=latest'); ?>">All</a>
```

Thank you
Radek

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, then you owe it to yourself to extend your Stack Exchange citizenship to [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Whenever you have a question that pertains to Joomla or would generally benefit from the support of volunteers with an intimate understanding of the CMS and its extensions, you should always ask your question on JSE.  Once you register on JSE, you can flag this question to be migrated to the dedicated community.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right.

```
<a href="/<?php echo EBR::_('index.php?option=com_easyblog&view=latest'); ?>"><?= \Joomla\CMS\Language\Text::_('ALL') ?></a>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation; please always post some plain English explanation with every answer.  Code-only answers are low-value on Stack Overflow.  If you are able to provide Joomla support, please extend your Stack Exchange citizenship to [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.